# Manipulate two div on one click using 'this'

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a minor college project which is kinda Social Network. I'm trying to add two option Like and Dislike. Everything is working fine but problem is that if a post is already liked by someone and then he press dislike, it will dislike post but it won't unlike post at the same time. Internally it working fine, means if someone dislike a post it will automatically unlike the post. But i'm unable to show it via ajax/jquery. kindly help.

Here i'm just showing jQuery part, in actual it is working with ajax.

```
$(".like").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).hasClass('liked'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('liked');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('liked');
        }
    });

$(".dislike").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('disliked'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('disliked');
    }
    else
    {
    $(this).addClass('disliked');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mpu8t/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the other control and then remove the class. Your HTML is quite simple so you can use the [`siblings` function](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find the correct element...

```
$(".like").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('liked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('liked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('liked');
        $(this).siblings(".dislike").removeClass('disliked');
    }
});

$(".dislike").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('disliked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('disliked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('disliked');
        $(this).siblings(".like").removeClass('liked');
    }
});
```

[Here is your example updated](http://jsfiddle.net/mK8GP/)

Comment: You might be able to simplify that by using the toggleClass function.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Yeah I noticed that from the other answer. However, I will leave this one as I think it makes it more understandable what is happening by keeping the original code as it is

Comment: actually toggle class won't work here, because i'm checking if it has `liked` class then run unlike ajax function and else run like ajax function.

Comment: @user3515181: That's a good point, if you have to do the check anyway then there isn't much point using the toggle

Answer (score 0):

So if i'm guessing correctly:

```
if you click dislike
  if it is already disliked
    unset disliked
  else
    'un-like'
    set disliked

if you click like
  if it is already liked
    unset liked
  else
    'un-dislike'
    set liked
```

if that is the case, then why don't you 'un-dislike' and 'un-like' it ?

```
$('.like').bind('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('liked').siblings('.dislike').removeClass('disliked')
});
$('.dislike').bind('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('disliked').siblings('.like').removeClass('liked')
});
```

fairly straightforward

Comment: via php i did this. but as shown in demo i'm unable to show it immediately using jQuery. :/

Comment: well, in your javascript code, you did not have code for 'un-like'-ing or 'un-dislike'-ing it. So yeah, that doesn't do much then :-)

Comment: thanks.. :) answer worked.. bt musefan posted answer before u, so i've to accept his answer. Thanx a billion zillion ^.^

Comment: @user3515181: Feel free to accept whichever answer works best for you. Although it is common to accept the first posted answer, this is usually only appropriate when the answers are pretty much the same. I think this answer differs enough to allow you to choose your preference

Comment: just here to help :-) Don't care about the points... unless 200k earns me a porsche ^_^